# C#: How to make a AutoComplete textbox using Google API in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, api, autocomplete

I'm actually trying to make something like this but in WinForms: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/places-autocomplete-addressform?hl=es

When you write some address, the TextBox expand and show you suggestions, and it updates every time you change the content of TextBox.

I write a method like `GetAddressPredictionsByInput(string input)` using Google API, but I dont know when I should call it, and how can I update suggestions like in the example, because if I change the `AutoCompleteCustomSource` everytime the `TextChanged` method is called, the control lost focus, and also too many calls to WebService freeze the program a little.

Hope you understand and help me.
Sorry for bad english.

**EDIT:**

Okey, I thought it wasn't necessary, this code is really simple and I explained it with words, but you down voted my question. This is my code:

```
private void textBoxEx1_TypingCompleted(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var autoCompleteListCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    autoCompleteListCollection.AddRange(new GoogleApi.Instance.GetAddressPredictionsByInput(textBoxEx1.Text).ToArray());
    textBoxEx1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autoCompleteListCollection;
}
```

**Update:** I partially answered my own question with:

I make a CustomControl that inherits TextBox and add a CustomEvent that is called when you stop typing for 2 seconds. Then, I call the method that returns an Array of Address (string) and I want to show it as suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Any code to show?  This will help us help you.  [mcve]

Comment: @MickyD Done! I thought it wasn't necessary, the code is really simple and I explained it.

Comment: Thanks for that.  It helps us understand the problem better.  +1